# vega-lite scatter plot with hyperlink on each data point is not clicking

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite

I am following [this documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/encoding.html#href) on making `href` channel inside the encoding of a vega-lite scatter plot.

The data I am using is from an elasticsearch index. This is my code for the plot:

```
{
  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json
  data: {
    url: {
      %context%: true
      index: my_index
      body: {
        size: 10000
      }
    }
    format: {
      property: hits.hits
    }
  }
  transform: [
    {
      calculate: datum._source.price
      as: price
    }
    {
      calculate: datum._source.size
      as: size
    }
    {
      calculate: "'https://www.example.com/'+datum._source.id"
      as: url
    }
  ]
  layer: [
    {
      selection: {
        grid: {
          type: interval
          bind: scales
        }
      }
      mark: {
        type: circle
        tooltip: true
      }
      encoding: {
        x: {
          field: size
          type: quantitative
        }
        y: {
          field: price
          type: quantitative
        }
        href: {
          field: url
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The code works and on hovering over the scatter points, the mouse changes to a recognised link however the click itself does not work. why is that? the only differences from the documented example is that the data is from `elasticsearch` and I have a second layer in the plot.

How can I make the hyperlinks work?

Comment: Your sample config is not working as it is not a proper JSON configuration, but i have understood your use case and provided a working example in answers.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the click selection, you need to provide a `selection` of `type: single`. Try click the points in the [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AFUINWWQAEAA0FImcQQFEAHjnXnTmNqYgw2Ad1NzBAE9TYzoaJEFTQThsOHUIfwAzUwQ5elNZJAQ1SkUVJEwUVFAGdUE0fMLOOALMaP4fGvo4yigIYhAAXyVkdQBrCqgadShovMx1JFkIRLZ1BDQAbVAoCKgGK0w4CoByLFx8Ih9j6jY2MmjWtgQdvKQICtLyzoBdJQhbOCgdOTRQD+i3z+IEwgRw23QRhMY063RAcFkUDYymMZGBMHUcESwMSNFsykeZS6SgcwJ02X0sjoFVSsnoeVx+IqygK2yUSAcNAexRAVhsggAgsIyHpeVjMHk+bZHM5mQUGAhKFLBIsAAwvLpwwLApBkMiYihbGk1eRKRmCAnoZxfLR0Aq6TWdIA) of editor or try the sample below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Using `labelExpr` to show only initial letters of month names.",
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "mark": "circle",
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "'https://www.google.com'",
      "as": "url"
    }
  ],
  "selection": {"select": {"type": "single"}},
  "encoding": {
    "href": {"field": "url"},
    "x": {
      "timeUnit": "month",
      "field": "date",
      "axis": {"labelAlign": "left", "labelExpr": "datum.label[0]"}
    },
    "y": {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "precipitation"}
  }
}
```